# I need to do a redirect on a proxied path in Nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, redirect

I'm working with a strangely architected app and I have a need to proxy / and redirect it to a sub-directory (unless someone can comeup with a better solution). Here's the layout of the paths the app uses:

```
var securePaths = [
    "/someaction",
    "/anotheraction",
    "/athirdaction",
    "/client/interfaceishere/index.html" //path to client interface
];
```

As you can see the place where the client interfaces with the app is two levels in so I need a redirect to there. I can't proxy the app there because it needs access to top level paths like "/someaction". I have nginx configured to the proxy the app like this:

```
upstream socket_nodes {
  ip_hash;
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
  server_name myapp.example.com;
  listen 80;


  location / {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  }
}
```

What's the best way to get the user down to "/client/interfaceishere/index.html"?

The previous users of this app solved this by iframing which is not an option for me.

Comment: You can play with location /path/..... or adding a path to proxy_pass, it depends what the backend is going to see, use curl to check responses and check logfiles to see where your going to.

Comment: Doesn't work, is there a wildcard location I can setup? Like: location /*

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is that I only want one path redirected (/) and everything else handled by the proxy. So a wildcard route for the proxy and a redirect for / would work but I can't find doc on a wildcard location.

Comment: so a proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/interfaceishere; doesn't work? If location is / and you ask for "/client/interfaceishere/" then proxy_pass should pass on the same path (uri), what do the logfiles say when you ask for "/client/interfaceishere/" ? I just checked my tomcat backend conf and it does / where any path is passed along.

Comment: That does work... but it proxies everything to:  127.0.0.1:8080/client/interfaceishere so a path of /someaction actually get passed like this 127.0.0.1:8080/client/interfaceishere/someaction where it should be 127.0.0.1:8080/someaction.

Comment: Then you need to split it up, the paths inside location blocks instead of passing everything with /. You really first need to think and write down where each path needs to go and then either use 'map' to redirect or/and location blocks to handle things. You can use location blocks to handle each uri separately.

Comment: I figured that might be the case. If you want to add this as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you need to split it up, the paths inside location blocks instead of passing everything with /. You really first need to think and write down where each path needs to go and then either use 'map' to redirect or/and location blocks to handle things. You can use location blocks to handle each uri separately.